# Messenger thinks my IP is invalid

Tags: instant-messaging, modem, windows-live-messenger, ip

I am using Windows Live Messenger 2009 on Windows 7. I am using a 3G modem (ZTE Propietary USB Modem)

I connect to the Internet using a software my ISP provided me. In last three days, my Messenger started to disconnect.

Here is what I observed and tried to do:

1- I can browse web, can do FTP transfer etc. and obiviously have a valid IP.

2- I can sign in to Messenger (appear offline) but when I change my status to anything other then appear offline, Messenger says my connection to service has been lost. (However, it exists.)

3- When I run, MSN Connection Troubleshooter, it says my IP is invalid. When I click repair, it says repaired and just after that, I run the troubleshooter again, and it says my IP is invalid again. (However, it is valid and I am browsing the net.)

4- If I connect the Internet through eterhet or wireless there is no problem at all.

5- I re-installed Messenger (deleting all settings manually through registry and folders), re-installed all drivers and software related to USB 3G Modem. It doesn't work. And then, I took a full backup then formatted entire computer, installed a fresh windows 7, after 5 minutes, the same problem occured.

What do you recommend? What can I do?

**Edit:**

As seen on screenshot, it says Server IPv4 adress is 0.0.0.0
It seems like a problem, I don't know if it is. If it is, how can I solve it?

[image]

Here is what I get, when I **netstat**.

> PPP adapter TTNET internet:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 217.174.39.122
>   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
>   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network
>   Connection 2:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network
>   Connection:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>   ege.edu.tr
>
> Ethernet adapter Local Area
>   Connection:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   16:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   13:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   9:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   11:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   12:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   14:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   17:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   25:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   20:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected
>   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection*
>   18:
>
> Media State . . . . . . . . . . . :
>   Media disconnected

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Start > Run
2. Type `regedit` and press Enter
3. Navigate to the following registry key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\MSNMessenger
   ```
4. Delete the `MSNMessenger` key

Comment: I already did that. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im) and see if that connects to MSN Messenger server?  If so, then you know it's your client software.  If not, then it's probably a network configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

First try opening a Command Prompt (`Win+R` and type `cmd <ENTER>` ) and type

`ipconfig`

If should display an information more or less like this:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Windows Mobile:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 169.254.2.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter AlphaQuadrant:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::10c9:8226:4914:72a5%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.186
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e74:3467:1786:36ec:a5e1
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3467:1786:36ec:a5e1%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

Then you need to check for the connection to the MSN server, probably some gateway is unreachable.

You can try, for instance `tracert` to check all the hops to the MSN Messenger.

Comment: I added my netstat output (editing my post). I don't know much, are there anything wrong in it?